# Android makefiles(.mk) documentation

Tags: android, makefile

I want to learn about android makefiles. How to write and modify them. Could you please guide me to the official android documentation related to this? Also Other helping resources would be of great help.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Official? http://developers.android.com perhaps?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The canonical reference (in my opinion) is Stallman's [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf). Posix Make is a bastard child. Posix make is anemic to the point it is worthless. So we use a portable make like `gmake` or `cmake` so we can actually do useful things. Android's make is kind of based on GNU Make (and friends), but its a real bastard. Its not intuitive, and its poorly documented. I despise working with it, and often create a makefile that performs a cross-compiles to avoid using `Android.mk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

- [Android.mk file syntax specification](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html)
- [Document by some user](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jDmWgVgorTY_njX68juH5vt0KY_FXWgxkxmi2v_W_a4/edit)
- [Pierr Chen's Blog](http://pierrchen.blogspot.in/2011/11/understand-androidmk.html)